# Cordinates of clicking event in eclipse display

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-gef

I am developing an eclipse plugin using Gef. I am creating a viewpart witch holds a 
canvas with my graph and everything I am drawing. Through mouse events on several figures I can get the click positions. Those positions are relevant to my viewpart. Is there anyway to get those positions/coordinates relevant to the whole eclipse window?

Thanks,
Kyriakos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example (How to place a Shell on top of a Figure) in the below article may help.  There is a map() method on display that converts relative coordinates of a figure into the relative coordinates a holding control, such as the main shell

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv/guide/coordinates.html